# Как можно вывести кастомное тело ответа при подвключении к ldap?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[image: Ответ]

На данный момент приходит такой ответ.Как можно его кастамизировать для более лучшей информативности? Происходит опеределенный вызов по адресу http://localhost:8095/v1/test1 с помощью
ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider,если сервер упал то выдается просто 500 ,как можно вернуть более информативное тело ответа?